# how to account for and remove compiled module size discrepancy

Tags: kernel-modules, make, embedded

I purchased an embedded (arm-based) Linux SBC and the manufacturer included an SD card with Ubuntu prebuilt.

I'm trying to recompile the kernel and modules to reproduce what the manufacturer shipped. I'm using [their kernel source](https://gitlab.conclusive.pl/devices/linux/-/tree/master/) and the config I found on /boot however there's a huge size difference between their modules and mine. My modules folder compiles to 147MB whereas theirs is 8.9MB.

I thought perhaps I was somehow compiling extra modules however I compared .ko files individually and mine are consistently much larger.

I gather it is possible to compress modules via CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS_* however this what is in the config within /boot:

```
CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS_NONE=y
# CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS_GZIP is not set
# CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS_XZ is not set
# CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS_ZSTD is not set
```

Could the manufacturer have overridden the compression settings when `make modules` was run? How else could the size difference be explained?

FWIW I'm cross-compiling from my x86 Ubuntu desktop to ARM, using the following commands:

```
make -j4 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- LOCALVERSION=-kstr-sama5d27 zImage
make modules -j4 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- LOCALVERSION=-kstr-sama5d27
make modules_install INSTALL_MOD_PATH=./modules ARCH=arm LOCALVERSION=-kstr-sama5d27
```

I see some guides recommend adding `INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1` to the install_modules command to reduce module size however this leads me to an error:

> strip: unable to recognize the format of the input file

**EDIT**: I tried manually stripping one of the .ko files using this command:

`arm-linux-gnueabihf-objcopy -g aes-arm-bs.ko aes-arm-bs-stripped.ko`

This file in particular is now much closer to original. 18376 bytes versus 19104 originally.

I also compared my compiled modules versus the supplied ones using `size` and I get the following:

- Supplied

```
$ size aes-arm-bs.ko
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   9047    2755      20   11822    2e2e aes-arm-bs.ko
```

- Compiled by me

```
$ size aes-arm-bs.ko
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   8893    2755      20   11668    2d94 aes-arm-bs.ko
```

Comment: Does the size decrease if you do `arm-linux-gnueabihf-objcopy -g modulename modulename-stripped`? (insert module name and give path to your cross compiler if necessary)

Comment: @Philippos yes it does decrease size, by about 10X

Comment: could you please use the **size** command for comparing your *.ko ?

Comment: @MC68020 I updated my question to add this info

Comment: So, as you see, irrespective of the file size, your are actually achieving better results (less RAM will be needed at runtime) than the supplied modules can claim. Therefore, at the end of the day, what is your real question about ? A couple of extra MB in file sizes ? Do you actually care ?